# How do I get the overlying text (like <h1>) to stop stopping the effect I want to happen on <area> when they're hovered over while using imagemapster?

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemapster

So I've looked elsewhere on StackOverflow and haven't come accross this problem specifically, **which is the negation of the effect on map < area > when hovering over texts (< h1s >) that are in & overtop that map < area >.**

There's a second point of interest as well which is **how to change all of the < h1 > element's colors to white when activating (or hovering) over a < area >**

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSaunders123/6ub4rnxw/2/)

```
<div class="map" >
<p class="map__text--1">North York</p>
<p class="map__text--2">Wellington</p>
<img id="vegetables" src="https://i.ibb.co/3FZHC33/map-popup.png" usemap="#veg" >
                <map name="veg" id="veg-map">
                    <area shape="poly" data-key="TO" alt="" coords="261,356, 252,355, 248,352, 238,347, 226,344, 220,345, 215,348, 209,351, 209,351, 205,348, 203,347, 200,345">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your problem applying an identifier on the `<area>` tag and applying global classname on each h1 element which *you can customise as you wish*.
Then i wrote this little snippet.

```
$('#example0').hover(
function() { $('.map_text0').hide(); }, 
function() { $('.map_text0').show(); });
```

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em3axu6d/), i hope it's what you are looking for.
(Yes, you can change their color too)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I was able to get all of them to change color and dissapear. Do you know though how to make it so that the h1s that are overtop the map area do not prevent the change of picture below them, when you hover on them

Comment: I think you should look at the following method: `preventDefault(...)` ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)) but i'm not sure about that.